# How can i retrieve list of method in jar without load all file jar in memory?

Tags: java, list, methods, jar

How can i retrieve list of method in a class in jar 
without load all file  jar in memory?
the application runs in a general purpose pc.
I find this :http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0513.html
In this source the program find the list of class in a jar but not find the list of method for each class.

Comment: From within a Java application? Or some other way? Providing more detail would be helpful here, along with anything you've already looked into or tried so far.

Comment: withinn a java application

Comment: Why are you concerned about loading the entire jar file? What problems are you encountering with that?

Comment: the problem is time beacuse i need to know the list of function of more than one jar file .

Comment: Do you have to look at a jar, or can you unzip it before your application runs? Give us a little more to work with here. Tell us where you're running this, what your limitations are, etc. As it stands, your question might get closed because it's too broad and rather vague.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean the you have different versions of the same class? In this case you can use a custom classloader.

Comment: and i think that if i load the jar i load also the code and for me is useless .

Comment: ok . the application need to know the list of method of general jar file . The application is unzipped before it run together  with set of "general" jar (that when the application runs will recognize the method).

Comment: no i haven't different version of that class i have some class in some jar that are independent between them.

Comment: the application runs in a general purpose pc.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the corresponding .class file from the JAR and analyze it using a bytecode tool like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).